# How to keep drawn things in canvas after invalidate

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-canvas, ondraw

for training, I'm writing something like 'achtung, die kurve' game. For now, I'm only about to simple drawing my 'kurve-snake' on screen. To turn I use accelerometer (and it does work in fact). I've custom view which has his own onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint2.setStrokeWidth(mPlayer.getLine().getmSize());
    paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    float x = mPlayer.getLine().getmPosX();
    float y = mPlayer.getLine().getmPosY();
    mLogic.movePlayer(mBitmapPoint, mPlayer, mSensorY);
    canvas.drawLine(x,y,mPlayer.getLine().getmPosX(), mPlayer.getLine().getmPosY(), paint2);
    invalidate();
}
```

It does work properly, but this way I can't keep whole line (just the actual fragment of it).

I've tried other way: draw lines using bitmap.setpixel (bresenhams alg) and after it canvas.drawBitmap(...), but it's not effective.

I've tried too:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint2.setStrokeWidth(mPlayer.getLine().getmSize());
    paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    float x = mPlayer.getLine().getmPosX();
    float y = mPlayer.getLine().getmPosY();
    mLogic.movePlayer(mBitmapPoint, mPlayer, mSensorY);
    canvas.drawLine(x,y,mPlayer.getLine().getmPosX(), mPlayer.getLine().getmPosY(), paint2);
    invalidate();
    mBitmapPoint = getDrawingCache();

}
```

but it gives error. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Please include the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your draw code to look more like this:

```
Point start = myPlayer.getLine().getStartPoint();

for(Point p: myPlayer.getLine().getPoints()) {
   if(start == p) {
      continue;
   }
   canvas.drawLine(start.x,start.y,p.x,p.y,    paint2);
   start = p;
}
```

You'll need to create a list of points which represent the "joints" of your snake, and there's a lot of code there I won't put here, but this approach will draw your lines out for you.

Comment: Adding to this, you should almost certainly never call invalidate() from within onDraw() as then the view will continue to invalidate itself forever.

Most likely, you want to use a Runnable in postOnAnimation to do your mLogic.movePlayer() and then postInvalidateOnAnimation() to force your view to re-draw after the move has been completed.

Comment: Ah nice catch, didn't notice that.  I'd upvote you twice if I could.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I've already handle with this problem (didnt remember to write this here). Yes, you both are right, but keeping joints-points could not be effective. In fact, it's better to use SurfaceView in program which redrawn itself 'forever'.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this demo, used to redraw on the same canvas multiple times,
[https://gitorious.org/freebroid/development/source/62e92d7a2a3fd2798901ec2e7c452ff0e4067163:samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.java](https://gitorious.org/freebroid/development/source/62e92d7a2a3fd2798901ec2e7c452ff0e4067163%3asamples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.java)